# How do I use finite population correction in SPSS?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, spss, finite-population

in our study, we have 80% of Norway's living brain cancer survivors. As we almost have sampled the entire population, we need to make a finite population correction. As this influences standard error, it will also influence B, partial eta squared and sig values in our regression. Making the correction to SDE is easy, however - making the adjustments in B, partial eta squared, t-values and sig is more complicated. We have searched online and asked around but cannot find a way to include this correction in SPSS. Is doing it by hand the only way?

Comment: In a regression setting it is a little implausible that you would confine your inferences to the population alone, suggesting that viewing all living brain cancer survivors as a unique population might be inappropriate.  More context concerning what you want to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, we are simply testing whether a model used for QOL in breast cancer survivors also explains variations in QOL within the Norwegian survivors of brain cancer. We have no need to generalize to an infinite population. Thus we need the FPCF. 

I have found an option within the complex sample wizard, but the numbers come out incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please be more specific about what parameters you are estimating?  The correction factors depend on the parameters and on the model.

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering! The dependent variable is a continuous z-score on measures of quality of life. The parameters included are ordinal values of the severity of neurological and endocrine illness following the brain cancer, ordinal values of the treatment aggressiveness and continuous variable for cognitive function as measured by standardized tests.

Comment: Is this an ordinary least squares regression and are you interested in the standard errors of the coefficient estimates?